# Is Call of Duty: Ghosts backwards compatible?

Tags: xbox-one, backwards-compatibility, call-of-duty-ghosts

If I have a Xbox 360 version of CoD Ghosts and play on the Xbox One can I play with people who have a Xbox One disc?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the case, yes. As with Black Ops 2's backwards compatibility check, players from both Xbox 360 and Xbox One were sharing the same servers. Keep in mind that servers for those games are no longer hosted by Activision, so that instead falls to player hosts.